# Valid OAuth2 redirect_uri for iOS dropbox app

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I am trying to integrate dropbox oauth2 in iOS application where i wanted to extract accessToken and dropbox ID and persist them on my server side.
 When i access https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize with *redirect URI*(**test-dropbox://userauthorization**) in iOS application, it is giving error as '***redirect_url must startwith https://***'

I am not sure of the right pattern where i wanted to redirect to my application after taking authorization from User.

Can some one suggest the right way to handle this.

Comment: Have you given the __url scheme__ in your app?

Comment: yup. I have used it. Same thing working for Oauth1. but failing with oauth2... oauth1 sample request : https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xxxxx&oauth_callback=oodly-dropbox://userauthorization

Comment: First, it's worth mentioning that we highly recommend using an official SDK instead of doing this manually. The official SDKs handle most of the work for you: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios or
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/ios

Comment: Regarding this issue, are you using the "code" or "token" flow? (I.e., specified as response_type.) As a matter of security, the code flow does require https://, except for localhost URIs. The token flow can be used with custom URL schemes like this though. So, assuming this is the issue, your options are to either use the code flow with a localhost URI, e.g., something like http://localhost/dropbox_callback or to use the token flow with your custom URL scheme.

Comment: @Greg, I have used dropbox SDK which is simple to use. Thank you for your valuable suggestion